# Wake up screen and show activity from service

Tags: java, android, service, wakeup

I have an IntentService running background and listening incoming TCP messages. When a desired message has been received, the device should wake up and MainActivity be on top.

I can start a new MainActivity and wake up the device, but then I have many instances of it. The best solution would be sending a broadcast message to the MainActivity, but then I cannot wake up the screen.

I have these permissions set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I have this in my onResume()

```
final Window win = getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

I can call even my onResume() function, but the screen is black. When I set MainActivity as singleTop, starting new MainActivity keeps the screen black.

Any idea?

Comment: Still having the problem...

Comment: Did you find a solution?  If so, please answer your own question.  Others will appreciate it!